# how to search file at server

Tags: linux, backup, terminal, database, file-search

i'm newbie at linux...

```
1. i want to make backup database(use mysqldump)
2. copy from server(use linux-server) to client PC (use linux- ubuntu 9.0)..
3. before that i want to search that DB file using terminal..
4. bcoz i dont know where the files are located
```

how to do that..?
please help i've never been do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps should be something like this:

Variant 1 - if you can't access the database directly over the network:
 0. Connect to server via ssh
 1. mysqldump   > /path/to/bakcup/file.sql
 2. Presume you copy over ssh: scp user@server:/path/to/backup/file.sql /path/to/local/file.sql
 3. you don't have to search **for** the db file, since you know where you saved it. I you want to search **inside** the db file for a particular string, you can do that with a lot of tools. As suggested above, *grep* is a good choice.

Variant 2 - if you **can** access the database on the server over the network:
 1. Be sure you have mysql-client installed on your computer (there are versions both for Linux and Windows PCs)
 2. use mysql dump (read the manual for exact parameters) to dump the file over the network directly to your computer

Comment: Or for variant 1, no SCP required: `ssh remotehost mysqldump > localfile.sql`

Answer (score 2):

Don't backup the raw database files. Use the database's dump tools (`mysqldump`, `pg_dump`, etc.) to get the actual data from the server.

Comment: and how search DB file?

Comment: with grep. the dump is plain-text.

Comment: can you give me an example??i have never use this